# node-rdkafka is not getting installed in local windows system as well as in remote linux server

Tags: node.js, npm, librdkafka

`node-rdkafka` needs ***Python 2.7*** as one of the dependency and it is already available in the system, path is also set for it.
Still `npm` is throwing errors related to `librdkafka` as per my understanding form the stacktrace.

Please find below the error thrown while installing the node-rdkafka in windows.

> node-rdkafka@2.6.1 install C:\Users\mrdeo\node_modules\node-rdkafka
>   node-gyp rebuild
>
> C:\Users\mrdeo\node_modules\node-rdkafka>if not defined
>   npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\....\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js"
>   rebuild )  else (node "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js"
>   rebuild )
>  Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To
>   enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
>    Getting
>   librdkafka from nuget
>  cl : Command line warning D9025: overriding
>   '/GR-' with '/GR'
>   
> [C:\Users\mrdeo\node_modules\node-rdkafka\build\node-libr
>   dkafka.vcxproj]
>  cl : Command line warning D9025: overriding '/GR-'
>   with '/GR'
>   
> [C:\Users\mrdeo\node_modules\node-rdkafka\build\node-libr
>   dkafka.vcxproj]
>    binding.cc
>  cl : Command line warning D9025:
>   overriding '/GR-' with '/GR'
>   
> [C:\Users\mrdeo\node_modules\node-rdkafka\build\node-libr
>   dkafka.vcxproj]
>  cl : Command line warning D9025: overriding '/GR-'
>   with '/GR'
>   
> [C:\Users\mrdeo\node_modules\node-rdkafka\build\node-libr
>   dkafka.vcxproj]
>    callbacks.cc
>    common.cc
>  cl : Command
>   line warning D9025: overriding '/GR-' with '/GR'
>   
> [C:\Users\mrdeo\node_modules\node-rdkafka\build\node-libr
>   dkafka.vcxproj]
>    config.cc
>  ..\src\callbacks.cc(103): warning
>   C4996: 'Nan::Callback::Call': was declared deprecated
>   [C:\Users\mrdeo\node_modules\no
>   de-rdkafka\build\node-librdkafka.vcxproj]
>   C:\Users\mrdeo\node_modules\nan\nan.h(1740): note: see declaration of
>   'Nan::Callback::Call'
>  ..\src\callbacks.cc(275): error C2589: '(':
>   illegal token on right side of '::'
>   [C:\Users\mrdeo\node_modules\node-rdkaf
>   ka\build\node-librdkafka.vcxproj]
>  ..\src\callbacks.cc(275): error
>   C2059: syntax error: '::'
>   [C:\Users\mrdeo\node_modules\node-rdkafka\build\node-librdkaf
>   ka.vcxproj]
>  ..\src\callbacks.cc(575): warning C4996:
>   'Nan::Callback::Call': was declared deprecated
>   [C:\Users\mrdeo\node_modules\no
>   de-rdkafka\build\node-librdkafka.vcxproj]
>   C:\Users\mrdeo\node_modules\nan\nan.h(1740): note: see declaration of
>   'Nan::Callback::Call'
>  ..\src\callbacks.cc(612): warning C4996:
>   'Nan::Callback::operator ()': was declared deprecated
>   [C:\Users\mrdeo\node_mod
>   ules\node-rdkafka\build\node-librdkafka.vcxproj]
>   C:\Users\mrdeo\node_modules\nan\nan.h(1638): note: see declaration of
>   'Nan::Callback::operator ()'
>    connection.cc
>    errors.cc
>   kafka-consumer.cc
>    producer.cc
>   C:\Users\mrdeo\node_modules\node-rdkafka\src/workers.h(42): warning
>   C4996: 'Nan::Callback::Call': was declared deprecat ed (compiling
>   source file ..\src\connection.cc)
>   
> [C:\Users\mrdeo\node_modules\node-rdkafka\build\node-librdkafka.vcxproj
>   ]
>    C:\Users\mrdeo\node_modules\nan\nan.h(1740): note: see
>   declaration of 'Nan::Callback::Call' (compiling source file ..
>   \src\connection.cc)
>   C:\Users\mrdeo\node_modules\node-rdkafka\src/workers.h(42): warning
>   C4996: 'Nan::Callback::Call': was declared deprecat ed (compiling
>   source file ..\src\kafka-consumer.cc)
>   
> [C:\Users\mrdeo\node_modules\node-rdkafka\build\node-librdkafka.vcx
>   proj]
>    C:\Users\mrdeo\node_modules\nan\nan.h(1740): note: see
>   declaration of 'Nan::Callback::Call' (compiling source file ..
>   \src\kafka-consumer.cc)
>   C:\Users\mrdeo\node_modules\node-rdkafka\src/workers.h(42): warning
>   C4996: 'Nan::Callback::Call': was declared deprecat ed (compiling
>   source file ..\src\producer.cc)
>   [C:\Users\mrdeo\node_modules\node-rdkafka\build\node-librdkafka.vcxproj]
>   C:\Users\mrdeo\node_modules\nan\nan.h(1740): note: see declaration of
>   'Nan::Callback::Call' (compiling source file ..
>   \src\producer.cc)
>  ..\src\kafka-consumer.cc(560): warning C4996:
>   'v8::Value::ToObject': was declared deprecated
>   [C:\Users\mrdeo\node_modul
>   es\node-rdkafka\build\node-librdkafka.vcxproj]
>   c:\users\mrdeo.node-gyp\10.15.3\include\node\v8.h(10046): note: see
>   declaration of 'v8::Value::ToObject' ..\src\kafka-consumer.cc(567):
>   warning C4996: 'v8::Value::ToObject': was declared deprecated
>   [C:\Users\mrdeo\node_modul
>   es\node-rdkafka\build\node-librdkafka.vcxproj]
>   c:\users\mrdeo.node-gyp\10.15.3\include\node\v8.h(10046): note: see
>   declaration of 'v8::Value::ToObject' ..\src\producer.cc(115): warning
>   C4996: 'v8::Value::ToObject': was declared deprecated
>   [C:\Users\mrdeo\node_modules\nod
>   e-rdkafka\build\node-librdkafka.vcxproj]
>   c:\users\mrdeo.node-gyp\10.15.3\include\node\v8.h(10046): note: see
>   declaration of 'v8::Value::ToObject'
>    topic.cc
>   ..\src\producer.cc(122): warning C4996: 'v8::Value::ToObject': was
>   declared deprecated [C:\Users\mrdeo\node_modules\nod
>   e-rdkafka\build\node-librdkafka.vcxproj]
>   c:\users\mrdeo.node-gyp\10.15.3\include\node\v8.h(10046): note: see
>   declaration of 'v8::Value::ToObject' ..\src\producer.cc(373): warning
>   C4996: 'v8::Value::ToObject': was declared deprecated
>   [C:\Users\mrdeo\node_modules\nod
>   e-rdkafka\build\node-librdkafka.vcxproj]
>   c:\users\mrdeo.node-gyp\10.15.3\include\node\v8.h(10046): note: see
>   declaration of 'v8::Value::ToObject' ..\src\producer.cc(396): warning
>   C4996: 'v8::Value::ToObject': was declared deprecatedworkers.cc
>   [C:\Users\mrdeo\node_m
>   odules\node-rdkafka\build\node-librdkafka.vcxproj]
>
> c:\users\mrdeo.node-gyp\10.15.3\include\node\v8.h(10046): note: see
>   declaration of 'v8::Value::ToObject' 
>  gyp ERR! build error
>  gyp
>   ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit
>   code: 1 
>  gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:262:23)
>   gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
>  gyp
>   ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
>   (internal/child_process.js:248:12)
>  gyp ERR! System Windows_NT
>   10.0.15063
>  gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js"
>   "rebuild"
>  gyp ERR! cwd
>   C:\Users\mrdeo\node_modules\node-rdkafka
>  gyp ERR! node -v
>   v10.15.3
>  gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
>  gyp ERR! not ok
>  npm
>   WARN commons-example@0.0.1 No repository field.
>  
>  npm ERR! code
>   ELIFECYCLE
>  npm ERR! errno 1
>  npm ERR! node-rdkafka@2.6.1
>   install: `node-gyp rebuild`
>  npm ERR! Exit status 1
>  npm
>   ERR!
>  npm ERR! Failed at the node-rdkafka@2.6.1 install script.
>   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely
>   additional logging output above.

Comment: is *librdkafka* installed? If not try installing it,  check this for details https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka